# AWS: Use Source in last stage in AWS-CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have a codepipeline pipeline that goes like this

- Source (github) -> Build (codebuild) -> Test (Codebuild)

The first two stages are working fine but for my last stage(the test stage) I'm trying to use `Source` as the `input artifact` because that's what I need but it's not going to work because you can't use `Source` outside of the first stage.

What is the protocol here?

Can you run the test in the first stage after the first `Source` stage is complete?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "because you can't use Source outside of the first stage" You can definitely use it in any stage as long as it is specified as the input artifact. "Can you run the test in the first stage after the first Source stage is complete?" Stages can be executed in any order in CodePipeline within reason.

Comment: I have Source as my input artifact in my third stage but get the following error `Source actions can only be included in the first stage of the pipeline`

Comment: That is a source "action" and not a source "artifact".

Comment: @Steve, the output artifact of the build stage should be and aggregate of your source and build stages, so maybe try taking the build output artifact as source to your test input, hope that helps